# Protect pivot table from mass assignment using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have following tables:

```
document: id, name;
author: id, name, job_title;
document_author: document_id, author_id, position
```

I'm passing an array of following structure:

```
$attributes = [name, job_title, position];
```

I'm trying to create author's model and attach it to document:

```
$author = \Author::create($attributes);
\Document::find($id)->authors()->save($author,$attributes);
```

Then I get `QueryException`, because laravel tries to mass assign attributes to pivot table, while it should only pass a `position` field.

The only solution I got is to filter array, like that:

```
$author = \Author::create($attributes);
$pivotAttributes = array_only($attributes, ['position'])
\Document::find($id)->authors()->save($author,$pivotAttributes);
```

Is there any better way, to define which columns of pivot table are fillable, better somewhere in the model or in it's relation?

Comment: If `$attributes` is a `Request` (or `Input`) instance, you could do `$request->only('position');`

Answer (score 2):

I was digging in the Laravel code and I did not find any good way how to specify fillable nor guarded parameter to Pivot class even though it is subclass of Model.

This means that you approach is pretty good already.

Comment: I see. But is there a way to extend Eloquent in order to do things like: `$model->belongsToMany(...)->fillable(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
$author = \Author::create($attributes);
$author->documents()->attach($id,["position"=>$request->get('position')]);
```

Show Doc
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Comment: Yeah. It still requires to describe fields outside of the model. Just a different perspective.